# Reprojecting coordinates and geoJSON in leaflet

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, geojson

I have a Leaflet map in default projection and a WMS layer also in default (Web Mercator) projection. I would like to add polylines and a geoJSON layer to my map, but the coordinates are in EPSG4326. I have figured out how to set the entire map projection, passing `L.CRS.EPSG4326` into the map object. But as I have a WMS in Web Mercator (no other projection options here), but polylines and geoJSON in EPSG4326, that does not seem to be an option.

I looked at the Proj4Leaflet plugin, but that also seems to pass a CRS into the map object.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Leaflet expects GeoJSON to be in EPSG:4326. In fact, the entire API uses 4326 (lat/lng), so you are good to go without any reprojection.

If you need to reproject GeoJSON, you could look at https://github.com/perliedman/reproject.