# problem transforming CRS coordinates EPSG:4269 to EPSG:3857 in python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, ogr, osgeo

```
source_srs = get_srs(shp_abs_path)
source_epsg = source_srs.GetAttrValue("PROJCS|GEOGCS|AUTHORITY", 1)
print source_epsg #prints 4269
target_epsg = 3857 # because these are headed to leafletjs
target_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
target_srs.ImportFromEPSG(target_epsg)
osr_transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source_srs, target_srs)
```

then as I enumerate through the shapefile I transform the bboxes on the fly

```
sf = shapefile.Reader(base_path)
shapeRecords = sf.shapeRecords()  #will store the geometry separately
self.shapefile_records[fn] = shapeRecords
for i, shape in enumerate(sf.shapes()):
    bbox = shape.bbox
    ## OGR/SRS TRANSFORMATION
    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(bbox[0],bbox[1])
    point.Transform(osr_transform)
    print point.GetX(), point.GetY()

    point.AddPoint(bbox[2],bbox[3])
    point.Transform(osr_transform)
    print point.GetX(), point.GetY()
```

which prints coordinates like this...

```
-13613708.5846 4623834.1438
-13613668.296 4623869.60132
```

these put me out in the ocean I think, but they're supposed to be in Napa county. Any suggestions are warmly welcomed. I can use almost any python lib.

NEW

I've identified an issue and I'm not sure if it's with osgeo or the 4269 to 4326 transformation I've defined. Have a look at this output:

```
>>> from osgeo import ogr, osr
>>> source_srs  = osr.SpatialReference()
>>> source_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4269)
0
>>> target_srs = osr.SpatialReference()
>>> target_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
0
>>> osr_transformation = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source_srs, target_srs)
>>> point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
>>> point.AddPoint(6449750.845, 2001628.41312)
>>> point.Transform(osr_transformation)
0
>>> print point.Transform(osr_transformation)
0
>>> point.GetX(), point.GetY()
(6449750.845, 2001628.4131199997)
```

Nothing is modified. I've triple confirmed the data is in EPSG:4269 and included a shortened bitly link to it below in the comments.

Comment: `get_srs(shp_abs_path)`come from ? source_srs is not an osr.SpatialReference()

Comment: gene it returns an srs object from another routine - something along these lines http://bit.ly/1prDBWU but returns the srs object

Comment: It's not clear if you have done it, but it's a really good idea to use `osr.UseExceptions()`

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your solution is that `source_srs` is not a valid `osr.SpatialReference()`. If the result of `source_epsg` is 4269 then:

```
source_srs  = osr.SpatialReference()
source_srs.ImportFromEPSG(4269)
```

gives a valid osr.SpatialReference()

#### NEW

If I understand correctly your question, you want to use Leaflet, and Leaflet expects coordinates and GeoJSON  to be in EPSG:4326 ([Reprojecting coordinates and geoJSON in leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55043/reprojecting-coordinates-and-geojson-in-leaflet))

If I project your results with osr

```
from osgeo import osr
wgs84 = osr.SpatialReference()
wgs84.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
merca  = osr.SpatialReference()
merca.ImportFromEPSG(3857)
transformation = osr.CoordinateTransformation(merca,wgs84)
print transformation.TransformPoint(-13613708.5846,4623834.1438)
-122.29402495095313, 38.313684256028715
transformation.TransformPoint(-13613668.296,4623869.60132)
-122.29366303230159, 38.313934175663768, 0.0
```

You can test the resulting GeoJSON:

```
 {"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [
 { "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -122.29402495095313, 38.313684256028715 ] } },
 { "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -122.29366303230159, 38.313934175663768] } }
 ]}
```

In [geosjon.io](http://bl.ocks.org/d/e6f27b90f0b5ced443c5) or [GeJSONLint](http://geojsonlint.com/)

[image]

The results are the same with EPSG:4269 (look at [Silly Geographic Precision](http://uxblog.idvsolutions.com/2013/11/silly-geographic-precision.html)):

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection", "features": [  
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -122.29402495095315, 38.313684256946736 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -122.29366303230159, 38.313934176581782 ] } }
]}
```

With target_epsg = 3857:

[image]

Comment: manually adding the EPSG codes makes the whole thing give me inf for my xy(s) (https://gist.github.com/minskmaz/8e0c655cb27be627b71b)

Comment: look above for the solution with Leaflet

Comment: Gene here's the [shapefile 22mb] (http://bit.ly/1CLMtMX) - ogr reports that its crs is EPSG:4269 - I would like to display in leaflet - however by way of your example I get coordinates that look like this - (58.24474028578448, 16.54020233041399, 0.0)

Comment: ogrinfo gives me [EPSG:2226](http://epsg.io/2226) as the prj file  `PROJCS["NAD_1983_StatePlane_California_II_FIPS_0402_Feet"..` and not EPSG:4269 - > result with a fragment of the map http://bl.ocks.org/d/bb676eea5d99a0de0695)

Comment: And other fragment with the Lake Berryessa (http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/raw/11ace59025f517366e51/)

Comment: Gene the issue I was having was that the pyproj identifier was interpreting the file as EPSG:4269. It's not clear to me why but when I used convert from 2226 to 4326 my geojson polygons properly project. I'm pleased but still vexed on the issue of how to automate identification of EPSG when source files originate in ESRI.Thank you for your input!!